# Same question, different program?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I had a problem that I wanted to solve regarding the program Numbers (macOS's spreadsheet program, analogous to Excel). I found a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/246614/making-line-charts-so-the-line-goes-through-all-data-points) that is the exact issue I'm having, but the answer is specific to Excel and (as far as I can tell) the solution doesn't map to Numbers. 
Before asking a brand new question I wanted the community's take on this.

- Should I ask a brand new question?
- Should I ask for an update via a comment?
- Should the question go to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## If it's a different program then it's a different (new) question.

Some of the features of programs might be similar, but that doesn't mean that the solution for one program applies to another.

It *could* be helpful to say that you found an identical problem for Excel, to help clarify your problem precisely, but your question is *not* the same.

Whether you ask here on Ask Different is your choice, but bear in mind that the audience there is exclusively Mac based and so you might get an answer quicker. There's nothing stopping you from asking here and we do have some awesome Mac people here and want questions from all platforms, but their community is more focused. 
We also don't really like [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

So ask away.

Comment: OK cool. Thanks for the clarification. I'll probably head over to Ask Different because of what you suggested, and because the `iwork-numbers` tag doesn't seem to be very heavily trafficked here :)

Comment: @Jeeter It's often helpful to link the related question in your question. It can both (a) forestall overzealous attempts to close as dup _and_ (b) give actual answerers a resource to adapt, if it's helpful.

Comment: In GENERAL, this shouldn't be an issue, which illustrates a fundamental flaw in SU:  Questions and answers are seldom identical enough to be beneficial to users by removing similar but essential pages, (which should include obvious links between similar pages).  The only useful alternative is for editors to be expert enough on that specific question to determine a "true duplicate".  Generalist editors could combine the two pages, but none of us are expert enough in specific issues to make great decisions.  I no longer contribute to SU, just to see my work destroyed.  Stop deleting pages.

Comment: @DaaBoss I'm not advocating deleting anything or marking anything as duplicate. In fact I'm stating the opposite, that a different program means it is distinct and separate and so not a duplicate. I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: I was generalizing about SU, and changes about editing I see that are necessary for both users, authors, editors, and SE itself.  I'm in a fairly large tech community, and I can tell you that many see SU's heavy handed editing and deleting ("duplicates" in most cases).  Though well intended, it is seen as extremely destructive, demotivating and frustrating.  Many chafe at any suggestion to visit SU unless absolutely required, and see contributing a waste time.   Maybe someday it will change, or I hope that there will be another SU-like site to replace it.